# How do you remove / alter statistics charts in Team City?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I want to remove some of the standard Team city charts such as "Success rate" and "Time Spent In Queue", how do I do this? Its documented [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Customizing+Statistics+Charts#CustomizingStatisticsCharts-Disablingchartsofparticulartypeonprojectlevel) who to do it, but this only seems to allow you to remove a subset of the charts, not including the ones mentioned above?

Also is there anyway to get the range to default to 'All' rather than 'Month', and to alter the x axis to be time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to disable project-level charts this can be done and is covered by the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Statistics+Charts#CustomizingStatisticsCharts-disable).

It isn't possible to remove pre-defined charts on a build configuration level.

From the [TeamCity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Statistic%20Charts#StatisticCharts-BCStatistics):

> In comparison with project-level charts, it is not possible to disable
>   pre-defined charts on the build configuration level.

This questions is tagged with TC7, but my answer is based on the latest version which is TC 9.0.4.